# two way binding not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a simple ng-repeat list, in which i am assigning current list item value to another property on the controller as follows:

```
  <li ng-repeat="num in list">
    <input type="text" ng-init="value = num" ng-model="value" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </li>
```

But when i click the Save button i get default value set for $scope.value. I expect the value for the particular input text to be displayed.

Here is the controller:

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
      $scope.value = false;
      $scope.list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
      
      $scope.save = function() {
         alert($scope.value);
      }
    });
```

How can i access the updated value of a input item in my controller on save function call.

Here is the plunker for the same: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q76EMPyOaCX9PbPkhDlU?p=preview)

**Update**: I am expecting the value to be fetched to controller without passing it as a parameter.

Comment: ngRepeat creates its own scope.

Comment: Okay, so how to retrieve the value.

Comment: You can pass value to save function, like `ng-click="save(value)"` accept the parameter and then perform your operation

Comment: I can do that, but that defies the two way binding purpose.

Comment: then use `ng-model="$parent.value" `

Comment: your plunkeris not updated

Answer (score 10):

Wow I can't believe most people have missed this. If you are using Angular 1.2 then you should definitely check out `track by` keyword in your ngRepeat directive.

```
<li ng-repeat="num in list track by $index">
    <input type="text" ng-model="list[$index]" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</li>
```

Bottom line **is stay away from primitive types when binding** since it will give you sync issues.

Fellas please put more time and effort into researching your solutions instead of just posting for points.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

ngRepeat create a scope, so, object is passed by reference and number by value.
Your code is problematic, if you successfully update the value, it will update all the numbers in ng-repeat. You can do this:

**html**

```
    {{value.val}} <!-- for check the value -->
<li ng-repeat="num in list">
    <input type="text" ng-model="num" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="value.val=num">Save</button>
  </li>
```

**javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
      $scope.value = {val:false};
      $scope.list = [0,1,2,3,4];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oq6zdeLd/

I'm sorry about my english...

Answer (score 0):

here it is how you can do that

```
<li ng-repeat="num in list">
    <input type="text" ng-init="value = num" ng-model="value" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(value)">Save</button>
  </li>


angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
      $scope.value = false;
      $scope.list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

      $scope.save = function(argument) {
         $scope.value = argument;
         alert($scope.value);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I am expecting the value to be fetched to controller without passing in a parameter actually.

Comment: according to me this is not Idea behind data binding.A controller's job with respect to Angular is to set up functions and properties that the view can use.please refer this                                                        [link](http://jonathancreamer.com/working-with-all-the-different-kinds-of-scopes-in-angular/)

Comment: @jsbisht In this case  you dont have to pass value as argument.              'angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', function($scope){
      $scope.value = false;
      $scope.list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    $scope.getValue = function(){
         $scope.ValuetoSave=  $scope.value;
}
      $scope.save = function() {
         alert($scope.ValuetoSave);
      }                                                                                        $scope.$watch('$scope.value', $scope.computeNeeded);                     
    });

Answer (score 0):

Lets not abuse the expression **"2 way binding"** ;)

Your controller has one scope and there is just one `$scope.value` in that scope. You cannot force is to have multiple values simultaneously.

`ng-repeat` creates new scope for each `li`. And even if you try to use `$parent.value`, your controller's `$scope.value` will only have the last assigned value in `ng-init`

You best bet in this case to pass the value as an argument. Hope this helped to explain the issue a little more. Correct me if I am wrong.