# AngularJS Directive Two-Way Data Binding Not Working When Observing Boolean

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a two-way data binding that is not altering the value of the variable sent to the directive.

My directive watches for a trigger and gives focus to the associates element (based on code found here at SO):

```
app.directive('focusMe', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      trigger: '=focusMe'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
        console.log("directive value: " + value);
        console.log("directive start: " + scope.trigger);
        if (value === true) {
          $timeout(function () {
            element[0].focus();
            scope.trigger = false;
            console.log("directive end: " + scope.trigger);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In the HTML I call it as follows:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value" focus-me="focusInput" />
```

When I trigger it for the first time, it works -- because the `focusInput` variable switches its value. But `focusInput` in the controllers scope (outside the directive) does not switch back to `false` when the directive completes.

This switch back to `false` should happen when I call `scope.trigger = false`, assuming I understand what should be happening.

What is missing that would cause the two-way binding to not push the value back to the variable passed into the directive?

**UPDATE 01:**

For posting the question I removed a small bit of code. The HTML actually looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.value" focus-me="focusInput" ng-if="item.condition != 'matches' && item.condition != 'does not match'" />
```

If the `input` fields hides and then is re-shown (based on the `ng-if`) the directive will properly give focus the first time `focusInput` changes. It will stop working again after that... unless the hide/show process is repeated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is a common problem when dealing with primitive values (boolean, int, etc..) within scopes.

I strongly suggest reading [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) article. (short answer: primitives are changed in the directive's isolated scope, and are not seeked up the chain for the parent scope, i.e., your controller scope).

As to how to solve your situation, I suggest to use dot notation and store your primitive inside an object, and bind this object to your directive:

```
scope: {
   triggerObj: '=focusMe'
},
```

And make sure your trigger references in the directive are now `scope.triggerObj.trigger`.

And in your controller have:

```
$scope.triggerObj = {};
$scope.triggerObj.trigger = true; //or false, what have you
```

Having an object will make sure the two way binding will work. And read the article above when you have time :)

Answer (score 5):

Directive create a scope. when you pass parameter to scope, object passed by reference and boolean (and number, string...) passed by value.

For example:

```
function changeToFalse(bool) {
    bool= false;
    console.log(bool);  // false
}


function changeObjToFalse(obj) {
    obj.bool= false;
    console.log(obj.bool);  // false
}

var obj = {bool : true};

changeToFalse(obj.bool);
console.log(obj.bool);  // true
changeObjToFalse(obj);
console.log(obj.bool); // false
```

See also same question - [two way binding not working with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261507/two-way-binding-not-working-with-ng-repeat).

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was the following:

```
parentCtrl  
-> directive1  
--> directive2
```

and I was trying to pass a parentCtrl.Model.variable through to directive2 with two-way-bindings.

The update was not working from directive1 back to the parentCtrl because of said issue. Using a dummy object in directive1, I would have also needed a watch to pass on the value to parentCtrl.

I ended up trying the following trick in directive1:
`$scope.scp = $scope;`
and binding directive2 to scp.variable.

The bindings works like this, but I do not know about possible downsides of this hack. Input welcome!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).