# I'd like to two bind a directive's scope, it appears its only one way bound?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, prototypal-inheritance

What I'd like to do is very simple: two way bind a directive's scope. This means given a Parent controller `ParentCtrl` with `$scope.name='Foo'` and a directive with `scope: {name: '='}` I'd expect that when I change `scope.name='Bar'` from within the directive's link function or `$scope.name='Bar'` from the given directive's controller I would expect that the the template for ParentCtrl would reflect the new `$scope.name`, otherwise it's only one way bound from the parent scope to the directive's scope. Unfortunately that is not what I am getting. Am I missing something here? Here's a plunker link illustrating the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VeGvWV2AGftFHF0LhnBY?p=preview

the code:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Bernie Sanders";
    $scope.occupation = "Arsonist";
  }])
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: 'Name: {{name}} Occupation: {{occupation}}',
      scope: {
        name: '=',
        occupation: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.name = "Donald Drumpf";
        scope.occupation = "Fascist pig";
        scope.$apply();
      }
    };
  });
```

the Template:

```
<body ng-app="docsSimpleDirective" ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
  Name: {{name}}, Occupation: {{occupation}}<br />  

  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div my-customer name="name" occupation="occupation"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You've created an isolated scope in your directive, why do you expect changes to be propagated upwards?

Comment: Because two way binding is extremely useful. What I'm really asking here is; is two way binding possible with directives?

Comment: Oh, I think I get your mistake - take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23699009/3707125 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29265539/3707125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you had multiple instances of `ParentCtrl`, 1st one is on body and then there it is on one of inner div.

So when you are declaring `name` on a scope variable, you are declaring it as a primitive type, so overriding value inside inner controller will simple have new reference for `$scope.name` value. Prototypal inheritance will only follow in case of `objects` not on primitive type variable.

You should do follow `dot rule` while defining `ng-model`'s on page.

Also no need to run digest cycle inside directive link function. That will end up throwing error. Please remove that from there.