# Angular boolean property is not updating outside directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I did one reduced [snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8vlLs?p=preview) of my problem. Actually I'm doing an app using ionic, but it doesn't matter, the problem occurs in the plunker too.

I've also read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29265539/6188402) and updated some of my code, but the problem persists.

---

I have this controller with an `object`:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.object = {
    boolean: true,
    btn1: 'Do it be TRUE',
    btn2: 'Do it be FALSE'
  }
})
```

And I want to change its `boolean` property inside this directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<button class="btn btn-default">{{$obj.btn1}}</button>'
    + ' <button class="btn btn-default">{{$obj.btn2}}</button>',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { $obj: '=myDirective' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var listener = scope.$watch('$obj', function() {
        if (scope.$obj) listener();
        else return;

        var buttons = element.find('button'),
          btn1 = buttons.first(),
          btn2 = buttons.last();

        if(scope.$obj.boolean){
          btn1.addClass('selected');
          $('#Log').html('true');
        }else {
          btn2.addClass('selected');
          $('#Log').html('false');
        }

        buttons.on('click', function(){
          buttons.removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');

          var isTrue = this === btn1[0];
          $('#Log').html(String(isTrue)); // works
          scope.$obj.boolean = isTrue; // does not works
        });

      });
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see while running the plunker, the angular log does not update like the jQuery one, and I'm giving both the same value.

I am struggling with this by hours, any help would be really appreaciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: As answered, you should REALLY be using ng-click for this and setting the Angular variable in scope, so you don't have to scope.$apply().

Comment: @ChrisStanley. Do you mean `ng-click` in the template and `scope.myFunction` in the directive, right? I thought changing the value in the directive would be better because actually I have four pages that needs this directive, then I can declare the function only once inside the directive. What would be the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shall notify angular that something has changed:

```
scope.$apply(function () { ... });
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jmpREvS9wtEwd6ePD8T8?p=preview)

P.S. use `ng-click` instead of jQuery click event.

Comment: Wow!! It worked, many thanks dude! .. I thought just the `=` in `scope: { key : '=' }` would do it .. :)

Comment: Following yours and @ChrisStanley' note to use `ng-click` the code worked without `scope.apply`... You dude are ninja