# ng-click="tab = $index" don't work in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in my app:

```
<li ng-repeat="name in tabs track by $index" ng-class="{selected: tab==$index}" ng-click="tab = $index">{{name}}</li>
```

and it don't work, selected class is enabled when I click on the item (each li I click have this class and it's not removed when I click other li) and tab is not updating, it work when I use this:

```
<li ng-repeat="name in tabs track by $index" ng-class="{selected: tab==$index}" ng-click="switchTab($index)">{{name}}</li>

scope.switchTab = function(index) {
  scope.tab = index;
};
```

why is this happening, why `ng-click="tab = $index"` don't work?

Comment: Are you able to get  `index` argument inside controller function?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak it was a typo it should be `scope.tab = index;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo, change to:

```
scope.switchTab = function(index) {
  scope.tab = index;
};
```

You used `$index` even though the parameter in your function is `index`.

**Edit:**
The reason it works with a function and not an assignment directly, is that `ng-repeat` creates a new scope. When you do:
`tab = $index` you create a new variable on that new scope, rather than updating the one on the `$scope` you think.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265310/angularjs-directive-two-way-data-binding-not-working-when-observing-boolean/29265539#29265539) for further in-depth info.

Comment: It was a typo when I added the code, the question was why `ng-click="tab = $index"` don't work, switchTab is working.